# .Net Compact Framework 2.0:  Deploying an app

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compact-framework

I was used to building on .Net Compact Framework 1.0 with VS 2003 where you had the option to "build CABs" for your project, which is handy because I am sending the app to a remote site.

Now this project was rebuilt with VS 2005 and I don't have this same "build CABs" option.  Is the deployment model with VS 2005 just to send the contents of the bin\Release folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For VS 2005 I would add a **Smart Device CAB project** to the solution and create the CAB with that using the primary output of the original project.

The **Smart Device CAB project** can be found under **Other Project Types/Setup and Deployment**