# Wireless barcode scanner

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-embedded-compact

I have 2 wireless barcode scanners. I have created an application in C# which reads a barcode and sends data to a web service which then manipulates the data and do further processing. When I start aplication, it first tries to connect to web service and will proceed further only if connection succeded. The problem I am facing is, if I deploy the application through visual studio then it works fine and connects to web service. But if I just copy the contents (exe and config files) manually, then it gives error that unknown host name. Can someone please help me to understand how this connection works? Does it needs some special settings in scanner device which visual studio does automatically while deployment?

Comment: Where is the web service hosted: on the box running the app, on the local net, or somewhere else on the Internet?

Comment: Are you deploying the application to a Compact Framework device?

Comment: This question of mine may help if you're deploying to a mobile device:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578591/net-compact-framwork-2-0-deploying-an-app

Comment: Hi, yeah m deploying to a compact framework device. And my webservice is hosted on a server, on LAN.

Comment: Are you sure that you get all of the necessary files when copying manually?  Are you sure that they are being put in the same location as visual studio is placing them automatically?

Comment: Can you please tell me what wireless barcode scanner you are using, as I myself am looking out for one. Does it communicated over Bluetooth or Wifi? Does it decode PDF417 or only 1D barcodes?

Comment: Hi Franklin, I am using 2 different types (manufactured by different companies) of barcode scanners, one is Symbol (Motorola) and other is Dolphin scanners. Dolphins take photo of barcode and process, but motorola one is infra red based, which makes motorola faster in barcode scanning. I am not sure about motorola but yes dolphin scanners are compatible for PDF417. I am using wifi. I hope it answers your questions.